# White Screen on a Frame with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, actionlistener, thread-sleep

I have a JFrame with a button, and when I pressed it show another frame, change things on the second frame and after 3 seconds, close it. I've tried this but when appears the second frame, it's in white.

```
private void smallButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        NormalCarEntry entryTicket = new NormalCarEntry();
        entryTicket.setVisible(true);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String entryTime = formatTime.format(date);
        String query = "SELECT `ticket` FROM `" + DB + "` ORDER BY `ticket` DESC LIMIT 1";
        st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (res.next()) 
            entryTicket.entryTicketLabel.setText(res.getInt("ticket") + "");
        entryTicket.entryDate.setText(formatDate2.format(date));
        entryTicket.entryHour.setText(entryTime);





        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        entryTicket.setVisible(false);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        

}
```

NormalCarEntry is the second frame mentioned.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Never call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread. This puts the called thread to sleep, and since the event thread is responsible for all Swing graphics and user interactions, your GUI will go to sleep. Use a Swing Timer instead.

Also, you will want to work on your search skills as this question is frequently asked on this site, and a little searching will bring you to a correct solution without need to add yet another of the same question here.

As an aside, you will not want to show a 2nd JFrame as an application usually will have but one JFrame. Instead either swap views with a CardLayout or use a JDialog for a dependent dialog window.